# How to prove that this is self-adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm given that I'm supposed to prove that this is self-adjoint. The question goes as follows:

> Assume that $~T ∈ L (V,W)~$, then prove that $~T^* T : V → V~$ is self-adjoint.

I'm not sure if I'm going in the correct direction, but I have the following intuition. If I take the adjoint of $~T^* T~$ I get $~(T^* T)^*~$ equals to $~T^* T~$ again by the properties of the adjoint such that $~(T^*)^* = T~$ and $~(ST)^* = T^* S^*~$.

Is this enough to prove that it's adjoint?

Is my intuition correct?

What more do I need?

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Yes that is enough to prove self-adjointness

Comment: I am assuming that $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional?